# Unable to enocde the result of wc_get_products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using the following code to get the best selling products and send the result in JSON. But I am unable to encode the result of wc_get_products().

```
    $best_selling_args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales', 
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num'
     );

    $products_posts = wc_get_products( $best_selling_args );

//  var_dump( $products_posts );

    echo wp_json_encode( $products_posts );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$products_posts_arr = (array) $products_posts;
echo json_encode( $products_posts_arr );
```

OR

```
function object_to_array($data) {
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $data;
}

$products_posts_arr = object_to_array( $products_posts );
echo json_encode( $products_posts_arr );
```

Encode array not object, `wc_get_products` will return object.

Comment: I am getting null.

Comment: Check I have updated code.

Comment: It's  still not working.

Comment: Added another method.

Comment: still not working.